# Подключение Maven библиотек к Tomcat

Tags: java, java-ee

У меня такой вопрос: как подключить сторонние библиотеки через Maven  к Tomcat. Я попробовал просто добавить их в pom.xml, но Tomcat их не видит (запускаю приложение с помощью Intelij IDEA).
Мой код в pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: чтобы томкат их увидел, необходимо чтобы эти библиотеки были в составе веб приложения (war)

Comment: а кстати почему именно томкат?

Comment: @Stranger как это сделать не подскажешь?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q как это сделать не подскажешь?

Comment: как Вы собираете war? или как Вы запускаете томкат?

Answer (score 1):

Через мавен тому нельзя добавить библиотеки. Их можно скопировать в lib каталог тома.
Если речь идет, о том, что при старте приложения требуются библиотеки, то в pom-файле они должны быть описаны как зависимости (dependency) без скоупа (как `mysql-connector-java` в вышеприведенном поме).

Чтобы собрать war, в поме нужно указать править тип собираемого приложения (по умолчанию это jar, если не указан тип), нужно в поме прописать

`<packaging>war</packaging>`

тогда соберется war файл.